# Dns lookup over SSL using cert provided with php

Tags: php, ssl, dns

In PHP I am Currently using shell_exec to execute a dig command for a particular partner who uses dns to get back ultra fast lookups for carrier info for phone numbers.  Currently this dig command goes over a VPN.  I need to move away from the VPN and go over ssl.  We have exchanged certs and now need to connect.  Being new to PHP, what should I use to do this? A socket?

Comment: There's no standard way to execute shell commands over SSL, AFAIK.

Comment: `stunnel` maybe? I guess you would have to force DNS to use TCP, but maybe you are already doing that.

Comment: Well I'm guessing I have to move away from the shell command but I still have to query dns over ssl somehow, they provided a java app that seems to work as I pass the trust store in as a parameter and it seems to open a socket over ssl and then query dns.

Comment: stunnel works but can't use because it doesn't do persistent connections, it closes the connection after each dig command no matter what settings I use.  I need another solution, anyone??